# Common input data examples?

Tags: input, data-mining, similarity

I'm trying to implement an approximate [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) system.

This kind of system create an association between input data and the result produced by an expensive computation. In this way, if the same **or a similiar** input is received again, we don't need to perform the same computation again.

In such a system, it's important that the input data received frequently  assumes similar values. If this doesn't happen, then it means that the system receives most of the times very different and not similar values, and so no association can be present in the system. As consequence, in such a scenario this system is useless.

Could you please give me some examples of such data, so data that they are not sparse or that they can be easily clustered or that they are related by a similarity function?